# Run different codes according to the selection from a checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am very new in PHP therefore I haven't been able to figure out how to run different code snippets depending on the check box we selected. So I would kindly ask for your help.

In my first page I have 2 check boxes, which are values that were populated from the mySQL database. Those two values were taken from a database table called "campus". Here is the code for the first page:

```
<html>  
<body>

<form action="functions_two.php" method="POST">

<div id="collegelane">College Lane campus:</div>

<?php

// to connect to database 
require("user_connection.php");

$q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['room'].'</br>';
   }

?>

</br>
</br>

<input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the output of the code above 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlj1n.png

Now, as you can see it has two check box values "C450" and "E300". When I select either one of these two values it takes me to the second page, where the value is echoed out. however what i want it to echo out is another piece of code according to the selection i make.

Say if i select "C450" i want it to run this code below, which creates another checkbox using values from the database table called C450, which i have already created:

```
<form action="final_page.php" method="POST">

<?php

// to connect to database 
require("user_connection.php");

// checkbox populated with values from database
$r = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `C450`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="bike" 
            value="'.$line['computer_no'].'"><label>'.$line['computer_no'].'</label></br>';
   }

?>

</br>

<input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

however if i select "E300" i want it to run this code below, which also creates checkboxes whose values come from database table called E300.

```
<form action="final_page.php" method="POST">

<?php

// to connect to database 
require("user_connection.php");

// checkbox populated with values from database
$s = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `E300`");
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="bike" 
            value="'.$line['computer_no'].'"><label>'.$line['computer_no'].'</label></br>';
   }

?>

</br>

<input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at `if` [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below if condition in your second page

```
// checks for the post method
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$checked_value = $_POST['car'];  // replace car to what ever it is in html form
}

// checkbox populated with values from database
$s = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM {$checked_value}");
```

Comment: And what happens `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {`

Comment: The query will fail as $checked_value will be undefined, I have seen lots of code like yours